# Downloading files using NSURLSessions is happening only when iPhone is Charging

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using NSURLSession to download the video files from server. I am using the following library [ObjectiveCDM](https://github.com/jameshuynh/ObjectiveCDM) . Download is working seamlessly when my device is connected to charging but when I am trying to download when my device not charging then download stopped. The above library is written using NSURLSession. Is the any way to override this property.

Comment: strange are you sure it's coz charge cable plugged or other issue. Coz there is not any restriction about cable plugged. you must be debug

Comment: @NitinGohel Yea it is strange. I checked all properties but I am unable to find solution.

Comment: have you check in another device? or change lib that you used for download

Comment: @NitinGohel Yea I checked many device few device its working fine and other all devices  I am facing this issue. Thats why i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can override this, assuming that the download isn't being initiated while your app is in the background.  See the [discretionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1411552-discretionary?language=objc) property on [NSURLSessionConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration?language=objc).

Comment: I tried it discretionary property, its not helping it.